# Eclipse Logcat filter plus sign not visible

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I have been using eclipse with Android for quite a while and all of a sudden, I don't see the filter(plus "+" sign) to filter logs by tags. I saw all buttons but still I am not able to get the + sign back. Has anyone of you faced the same problem. Please let me know the fix. Thank you. phew..!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the right side of your Logcat, click the icon named **Display Saved Filters View**(near to Scroll Lock icon).